# Where am i wrong with __() wp

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin and after the initial review some warnings/errors were listed by WP community.

> __('home application','bull-home');
>    don't use __ to prefix, as the double underscore should be reserved for WordPress itself.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: That function is for translations

Comment: Yes, so what is wrong with this?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: Seems like you have a conflict in function naming.

Comment: i'v checked all my functions. no functions are prefixed with __

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116913/discussion-between-shiva-acharjee-and-laser).